# Has_many :through Rails 4 Instance variable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, strong-parameters

I have problem with strong params in `Ruby on Rails 4`. 
I have 3 models `Entity`, `user`, `user_entity`.

`User_entity` ties together `entity` and `user` with `has_many :through` association.

Here is code that works perfectly!

/views/user_entity/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @user_entity.user_id %>
</p>
```

And here when I modify it it doesn't!

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @user_entity.user.name %>
</p>
```

Error I get is this:

> undefined method `user' for # Extracted
>   source (around line #433):
>         else
>           match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
>           match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
>         end
>       end

I think it is because of `strong params` not allowing me to access data from `user` controller, but i have no idea how to whitelist that data to `user_entity` model.

Please help.

/models/entity.rb

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_entities
  has_many :user_entities
  has_many :users, :through => :user_entities
end
```

/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_entities
  has_many :user_entities
  has_many :entities, :through => :user_entities
end
```

/models/user_entity.rb

```
class User_entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entities
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Comment: Can you add your `User`, `UserEntity`, and `Entity` models to your question?

Comment: + how do you define @user_entity? You have a typo "eser_entity" above, I guess it's just here and not in your actual code?

Comment: Mistype: `@eser_entity` instead `@user_entity`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misspelled `<%= @eser_entity.user.name %>`

It should be `<%= @user_entity.user.name %>`

**Edit:**

In /models/user_entity.rb you used `class User_entity` for your model's class name. Class names are expect to be CamelCased:

```
class UserEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Comment: Also, it is just a sample. in reality i use one work, so it won't be the solution. here is the tutorial i'm stuck at http://www.gitmatt.com/posts/5 problem is i can't use `attr_accessible` with rails 4. those strong params are making this error. At least i think so.